# Collect instances via LiftAll

Tags: scala, shapeless

I'm trying to describe the types which a case class contains.

```
import shapeless._
import shapeless.ops.hlist.LiftAll

trait Desc[T] {
  def description: String
}

case class Foo(f: Int)
object Foo {
  implicit val description: Desc[Foo] = new Desc[Foo] { val description = "foo" }
}

case class SomeCaseClass(f: Foo)

val gen = Generic[SomeCaseClass]
val lifted = implicitly[LiftAll[Desc, gen.Repr]].instances.toList
```

Gives me

```
could not find implicit value for parameter toTraversableAux: shapeless.ops.hlist.ToTraversable.Aux[shapeless.ops.hlist.LiftAll[Playground.this.Desc,Playground.this.gen.Repr]#Out,List,Lub]
not enough arguments for method toList: (implicit toTraversableAux: shapeless.ops.hlist.ToTraversable.Aux[shapeless.ops.hlist.LiftAll[Playground.this.Desc,Playground.this.gen.Repr]#Out,List,Lub])toTraversableAux.Out.
Unspecified value parameter toTraversableAux.
```

Scastie here: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/bXu71pMQQzCqrrsahVBkWA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you summon an implicit instance with `implicitly[LiftAll[Desc, gen.Repr]]` then the dependent type `Out` of `LiftAll` is lost, so the compiler doesn't know which type exactly `instances` will return.

To work around this problem most typeclasses in Shapeless define an `apply` method in their companion object which does retain all dependent type information. It's the reason that you can use `gen.Repr` in a meaningful way after calling `val gen = Generic[SomeCaseClass]`. For some reason however `LiftAll.apply` was [not implemented in this way](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/pull/697). So that leaves you the option of implementing your own `implicitly`, or since you're using Shapeless anyway, use its `the` which is supposed to be a better `implicitly`.

```
scala> def impl[T <: AnyRef](implicit ev: T): ev.type = ev
impl: [T <: AnyRef](implicit ev: T)ev.type

scala> impl[LiftAll[Desc, gen.Repr]].instances.toList
res1: List[Desc[Foo]] = List(Foo$$anon$1@40b3708a)

scala> the[LiftAll[Desc, gen.Repr]].instances.toList
res2: List[Desc[Foo]] = List(Foo$$anon$1@40b3708a)
```

You can see the difference here in the inferred types that the REPL displays:

```
scala> impl[LiftAll[Desc, gen.Repr]]
res3: LiftAll.Aux[Desc,Foo :: HNil,Desc[Foo] :: HNil] = shapeless.ops.hlist$LiftAll$$anon$206@384d060c

scala> implicitly[LiftAll[Desc, gen.Repr]]
res4: LiftAll[Desc,gen.Repr] = shapeless.ops.hlist$LiftAll$$anon$206@30787774
```